# How do I define the text color in the search field if I start writing with an asterisk or a chosen letter?

Tags: javascript, html

With this js code we can hide a div when starting with an asterisk or show the div when starting with a letter or other symbol. And what I need is to change the color of the text that I write when I start with an asterisk. That is, if I start with a letter or symbols the div appears below and remains black, but if I start with an asterisk the div does not appear but the asterisk and the following words that I write must appear in green.

https://jsfiddle.net/z6cgxjek/

```js
    $('#search').keyup(function(event) {
    $('#hello').show();    
    if(!event.target.value.trim() || event.originalEvent.charCode === 42 || event.target.value.startsWith("*")) {
      $('#hello').hide();
    } else {
      $('#hello').show();
    }
});
```

```css
#hello {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<input id="search" autocomplete="off"/>
<div id="hello" >Hello World!</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [**`.css()`**](https://api.jquery.com/css/) to get/set one or more CSS properties. I will also prefer *input* event instead of *keyup* here:

```js
$('#search').on('input', function(event) {
  $('#hello').show();    
  if(!event.target.value.trim() || event.originalEvent.charCode === 42 || event.target.value.startsWith("*")) {
    $('#hello').hide();
    $(this).css({color: 'green'});
  } else {
    $('#hello').show();  
    $(this).css({color: ''});
  }
});
```

```css
#hello {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="search" autocomplete="off"/>
<div id="hello" >Hello World!</div>
```